# Include pointer in array of pointer

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform

I have a collection of Video objects that I'm trying to fetch from Parse. Each video has a property called mostRecentComments which is an array containing pointers of Comment objects, containing the comment body and creator. On the client, I attempt to present these comments in such a way where it displays "`comment.creator.username` `comment.body`." I'm trying to figure out how to include the creator in the array of most recent comments of each video that is returned from my Cloud Code, trying to avoid having to run something like:

```
var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
_.map(video.get("mostRecentComments"), function (comment) {
  promise = promise.then(function () {
    return comment.fetch();
  }).then(function (fetchedComment) {
    return fetchedComment
  });

  return promise;
});
```

because of the risk for a timeout.

Context:

```
   videoQuery.include("place");
    videoQuery.include("creator");
    videoQuery.include("mostRecentComments");

    videoQuery.descending("createdAt");

    videoQuery.equalTo("isAvailable", true);

    videoQuery.limit(30);

    if (page > 0) {
        videoQuery.skip(30 * page);
    }

    likesQuery = user.relation("likes").query();
    likesQuery.matchesKeyInQuery("objectId", "objectId", videoQuery);
    Parse.Promise.when([likesQuery.find(), videoQuery.find()]).then(function (likes, videos) {
        var results = [];

        if (videos.length == 0) {
            response.error("Could not find video results");
            return;
        }

        _.each(videos, function (video) {
            result = {
                video: video,
                isLiked: false
            };

            _.each(likes, function (like) {
                if (like.id == video.id)
                    result.isLiked = true;
            });

            results.push(result);
        });

        var next_page = (videos.length == 30) ? page + 1 : -1;
        response.success({
            results: results,
            next_page: next_page,
            previous_page: page
        });
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to include that data since you are not running a query. Maybe you can call the relevant `fetch` function in your client?

Comment: I wish it was that easy... The cells in my table view are dependent on knowing the size of the comments about to be displayed, and it'd be preferable to not have to wait on the fetch.

Comment: I actually am using a query, updated to include code

Comment: I see. Well, I think the problem is that you have to fetch the data regardless. Any way you could make it a OneToMany relationship instead of an array? Then just query for the most recent ones

Comment: I have a relation to the Comment class stored in the "comments" field of each video, the only issue I see with querying for that is that I'd have to do it on each of the 30 videos that come back, again pushing the limit for the timeout

Comment: I don't think Parse has a way to do what you are trying to do currently. You might have to redesign the relationship. The timeout for Cloud Code is 30 seconds - even if you do query for everything, does it run for that long?

Comment: I modified it to query for every video... Now the issue is that it's painfully slow coming down to the client

Comment: Do you need to know how many comments there are for ALL of the videos initially? Maybe you could fetch the first video's comments and display those, then on the client fetch the comments for the others in the background. Otherwise I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: i do, but i keep that as a property of each video. I've built somewhat of an API in my cloud code

Comment: So then can you do what I suggested above? Since you already know how many comments there are, fetch the other ones in the background on the client. If that doesn't work I have no other suggestions.